# Java Hibernate field access property or property based access

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

i am developing some improvements over a legacy system have some quite time

i have a class like this

```
class MyPersistentClazz
{
      private String aTPlace;
      public void setATPlace(.......){......}//yes mistyping    
      @Column(name="atPlaceOrder")
      public String getATPlace(){return aTPlace;}
}
```

they usually load this class using this methods

```
final MyPersistentClazz clazz = (MyPersistentClazz)session.createCriteria(MyPersistentClazz.class).add(idEq(id)).uniqueResult();
```

and using *load* and *get* methods and works OK.

but the problem arise when i use projections.

```
final Projection p=Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("d.aTPlace"),"aTPlace");
```

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
```

my question is...

*when using projections i think Hibernate is calling the setter of each property is this assertion OK?*

*when using criteria.uniqueResult or load or get Hibernate use individual field property access?*

or why works with some and not work with others with the same setter?

we are using only annotations not XML.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How Hibernate works with your bean depends on how you annotated it. If you annotate instance variables then Hibernate will use direct injection and bypass your Set methods. Otherwise, it will use your Set methods.

Could it be that it is incorrectly converting your property name to a Set method name? Try changing the property name to something simpler (without that series of capital letters), and ensure that the case of the property in your projection is correct.

Comment: hey phil... yes in fact is working now.. setting the setters and getters correctly... i post the question because is strange for me and i want to understand.. please check my edited question we are using annotations not XML

Comment: I didn't assume, or mention, XML. If you annotate get methods instead of properties, then Hibernate will use get/set. However I wasn't explicit about this as nobody ever annotates the methods...